# @use_kwargs changes response content

Tags: flask, flask-apispec

I notice that `@use_kwargs` in `flask-apispec` changes the response content-type. In the following "hello world" example, The use of `@use_kwargs` changes the response content-type from `text/html` to `application/json`.  I find it a bit surprising since the [flask-apispec doc](https://flask-apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#flask_apispec.annotations.use_kwargs)  doesn't mention it and I wouldn't expect injecting args also changes the response type:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_apispec import use_kwargs
from marshmallow import fields

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@use_kwargs({'email': fields.Str()}, location="query")
def hello_world(**kwargs):
    return 'Hello, World!
```

`curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/\?email\=abc`  shows the response

```
> GET /?email=abc HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 16
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.8.2
< Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 06:09:25 GMT
<
"Hello, World!"
```

Note that the `Content-Type: application/json` and value *hello world* is quoted.  However,
without the line of `@use_kwargs`, the response is of `Content-Type: text/html`  and the content *hello world* is not quoted:

```
~ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/\?email\=abc
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /?email=abc HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 13
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.8.2
< Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 06:09:42 GMT
<
* Closing connection 0
Hello, World!%
```

What is the rationale of changing the response? How can I set the response content type of "text/html" even with the use of `@use_kwargs`? Thank you !

**Update:**

Just add a bit more details on the answer given by @Diego Miguel:
The effect of changing content is caused by the logic in [Wrapper.**call**](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec/blob/de6f5adbcf3e6fce14aa1e1288ac2e401fd9ca35/flask_apispec/wrapper.py#L28)

```
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self.call_view(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(response, werkzeug.Response):
            return response
        rv, status_code, headers = unpack(response)
        mv = self.marshal_result(rv, status_code)
        response = packed(mv, status_code, headers)
        return flask.current_app.make_response(response)
```

`marshal_result` calls [flask.jsonify](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) which makes a [Response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response) object with  "application/json" mimetype and also introduces an extra level of quotation of the "hello world" example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why using `@use_kwargs` changes the content-type. By looking at the [source code](https://flask-apispec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/flask_apispec/annotations.html#use_kwargs), it seems to return a `dict`, judging by this [function](https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec/blob/de6f5adbcf3e6fce14aa1e1288ac2e401fd9ca35/flask_apispec/utils.py#L92) (that is called by `activate`). So my best guess is that Flask when executing `app.route` jsonifys that `dict`, as that the [default behaviour](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Response). At that point, the `content-type` is changed to `application/json`. However, `hello_world` is executed after `use_kwargs`, finally returning a string, that is, "Hello World!".

In any case, I don't think this behaviour is actually intended by `flask-apispec`.

You can change the `content-type` of your response (and any other field), creating a `Flask.Response` object with `make_reponse` and then setting its `content-type` to `"text/html"` (however, this is set by default when passing a string to `make_response` so it's not necessary):

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_apispec import use_kwargs
from marshmallow import fields

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@use_kwargs({'email': fields.Str()}, location="query")
def hello_world(**kwargs):
    response = make_response("Hello World!")
    response.content_type = 'text/html'  # can be omitted
    return response
```

Output of `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000/\?email\=abc`:

```
> GET /?email=abc HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 13
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.1
< Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 19:08:05 GMT
< 
Hello World!
```